# I can't correctly access cached images while offline

Tags: java, android, caching, android-asynctask

I'm using [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) to help cache some images. I know for fact the images are being cached correctly, but I'm having trouble accessing them unless I'm online.

I know they are being cached because I can see them on my SD card and if I replace `mArtistImageURL` in my return statement with the URL from my browser (copy/paste), the image will load while I'm offline, if it's already cached. I realize that I'm requesting to fetch the image URLs only if I'm online, but even so, I don't understand why the cached images won't load offline.

`MusicUtils.isOnline()` is basically a check to see if there is any connection. The main reason I have the bulk of my `doInBackground()` method wrapped in this is do to an Exception being thrown if I don't. `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1` is all Logcat is putting out for me at the moment. I'm not sure why the stacktrace isn't complete.

I've tried using my `AsyncTask` in every way I know. I've returned a `Bitmap`, `File`, and `String` and I'm able to successfully load the image in each case, as long as I'm online. So, I have these cached images and I need some help putting them to use.

**AsyncTask**

```
    public class loadArtistImage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // Get artist image
        if (MusicUtils.isOnline(mContext)) {
            mArtistResults = Artist.getImages("Andrew Bird", 1, 1, key);
            mArtistIterator = mArtistResults.getPageResults().iterator();
            while (mArtistIterator.hasNext()) {
                mArtistImageURL = mArtistIterator.next().getImageURL(
                        ImageSize.ORIGINAL);
            }
        }
        aq.cache(mArtistImageURL, 60000 * 1440);
        return aq.getCachedImage(mArtistImageURL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bm = result;
        if (bm!= null) {
            mArtistImage.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mArtistImage.startAnimation(AnimationUtils
                            .loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.fade_in));
                    MusicUtils.setArtistBackground(mArtistImage, bm);
                }
            }, 666);
        } else {
            // TODO something
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mm. While offline what the value of mArtistImageURL will be? Null? So at this point `aq.cache(mArtistImageURL, 60000 * 1440);` you are caching null, and at next line you are trying to get cache for null? Am I right?

Update: I suppose you cache images using url hash value for file name or something like this. So, modify your cache method to accept additional parameter for filename, for example `aq.cache(mArtistImageURL,mArtistNameWithoutSpaces, 60000 * 1440);` and when you want a file offline just call `aq.getCachedImage(mArtistNameWithoutSpaces);` so it will look at your cache folder and return a right file, or stub image if no file is found.

Update 2: Okay, if you dont want to modify AQuery cache methods you can try (againg) using shared preferences (so they would work) like this (not tested):

```
public String getUrlForArtist(String artistName) {
        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
                "artistImages", 0);
        return settings.getString(artistName, "http://default.url");
    }

public void setUrlForArtist(String artistName, String url) {
        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
                "artistImages", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(artistName, url);
        editor.commit();
}
```

So in the end your code will look something like this:

```
if (MusicUtils.isOnline(mContext)) {
            mArtistResults = Artist.getImages("Andrew Bird", 1, 1, key);
            mArtistIterator = mArtistResults.getPageResults().iterator();
            while (mArtistIterator.hasNext()) {
                mArtistImageURL = mArtistIterator.next().getImageURL(
                        ImageSize.ORIGINAL);
            if(mArtistImageURL!=null)
             setUrlForArtist("Andrew Bird", mArtistImageURL);
            }
        } else
              mArtistImageURL = getUrlForArtist("Andrew Bird");
```

Oh, yeah, I dont know how AQuery behaves, but anyway you probably should only cache images while online.

Comment: Yeah, I realize this, you're right. The things is, I'm not sure how else to go about this. I can't think of a way to maintain the value of the URL while I'm offline. I've tried `SharedPreferences`, but they never worked. I have to catch the Exception thrown by the methods I'm using to fetch the image URL when I'm offline, or else, it force closes of course. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but what method, `getImageUrlOrFilenameWhileOffline()`, could return the correct image URL if I need to be online to grab it in the first place?

Comment: One image per artist, that's right. Of course, `Andrew Bird` is only a test.

Comment: The params for `AQuery.cache()` are `String` and `Long`. I know what you mean, but I couldn't do that unless I modified the source of AQuery. I mean, it's open sourced, but there's a better way.